# Compiling resource bundles in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, locale

I want to compile my locale, resource.properties file into a swf.

How can I do that??

The documentation on Adobe site seems to be insufficient.

Can someone please help.

### Thanks

Neera

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this post from Sönke Rohde will help you: http://soenkerohde.com/2008/07/flex-localization/
He explains how to set up the localization in Flex.

Maybe you should also have a look at BabelFX: http://babelfx.org/

Answer (score 1):

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=l10n_1.html

You can't do it directly from Flash Builder, you need to write a shell, ANT or Maven build script.